# In Safari Element appearing at wrong spot on page

Tags: css, safari, mootools

I'm experiencing a very strange problem on Safari. I have a menu that when the user scrolls below the viewport is fixed to the top of the screen, with the following function attached to the scroll event:

```
  function menuFix() {
     if ( $$('body').pick().hasClass('project') ) {
                return;
            }

            var el = $$('.menu').pick(),
                scroll = window.getScroll(),
                scrn = window.getSize();
            if ( scroll.y >= scrn.y ) {
                el.setStyles({
                    'position':'fixed',top:'0',
                    '-moz-box-shadow': '0 10px 6px -6px #ccc',
                    '-webkit-box-shadow': '0 10px 6px -6px #ccc',
                    'box-shadow': '0 10px 6px -6px #ccc'
                });
            } else {
                el.setStyles({
                    position:'',
                    top: '',
                    '-mox-box-shadow': '',
                    '-webkit-box-shadow': '',
                    'box-shadow': ''
                });
            }
        }
```

The default settings on the .menu are:

```
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6rem; 
}
```

In Chrome and Firefox, this works well. In Safari, I have a very strange problem. If you scroll down, the menu is fixed to the top of the viewport as it should be. However, if you scroll back up, especially if you do so with some velocity, the menu is fixed in the wrong spot. It looks like this:

[image: Menu Appearing in Wrong Spot]

I thought that this might be related to my use of the relatively new vh attribute, but when I changed the above code to explicitly set `top` to the viewport height by changing the code like so:

```
 function menuFix() {
     if ( $$('body').pick().hasClass('project') ) {
                return;
            }

            var el = $$('.menu').pick(),
                scroll = window.getScroll(),
                scrn = window.getSize();
            if ( scroll.y >= scrn.y ) {
                el.setStyles({
                    'position':'fixed',top:'0',
                    '-moz-box-shadow': '0 10px 6px -6px #ccc',
                    '-webkit-box-shadow': '0 10px 6px -6px #ccc',
                    'box-shadow': '0 10px 6px -6px #ccc'
                });
            } else {
                el.setStyles({
                    position:'',
                    top: scrn.y,                // changed line to explictly set viewport height
                    '-mox-box-shadow': '',
                    '-webkit-box-shadow': '',
                    'box-shadow': ''
                });
            }
        }
```

I experienced the same problem. In fact, when I highlighted the element in Safari's dev tool, it put the highlight around the spot where the element **should have been** and not where the element actually appeared! It looked like this:

[image: Safari Showing Where the Menu Should Have Appeared]

Anyone know what might be going on here? This seems pretty buggy!

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I tried, but so far I can't replicate it: http://jsfiddle.net/r7gcgtuL/6/

Comment: Hmmm, hard to help without seing the problem... do you have a online version? Is it only Safari?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem with you. How can you solve it?